# Need to filter, parse and sort multiple log files

Tags: java, arrays, regex, grep

I have a need to collect a subset of info from log files that reside on one-to-many log file servers.  I have the following java code that does the initial data collection/filtering:

```
public String getLogServerInfo(String userName, String password, String hostNames, String id) throws Exception{
    int timeout = 5;
    String results = "";
    String[] hostNameArray = hostNames.split("\\s*,\\s*");

    for (String hostName : hostNameArray) {
        SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
        ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());

        try {
            Utils.writeStdOut("Parsing server: " + hostName);
            ssh.connect(hostName);
            ssh.authPassword(userName, password);
            Session s = ssh.startSession();

            try {
                String sh1 = "cat /logs/en/event/event*.log | grep \"" + id + "\" | grep TYPE=ERROR";
                Command cmd = s.exec(sh1);
                results += IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString();

                cmd.join(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Utils.writeStdOut("\n** exit status: " + cmd.getExitStatus());
            } finally {
                s.close();
            }
        } finally {
            ssh.disconnect();
            ssh.close();
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

The `results` string variable looks something like this:

> TYPE=ERROR, TIMESTAMP=10/03/2015 07:14:31 253 AM, HOST=server1, APPLICATION=app1, FUNCTION=function1, STATUS=null, GUID=null, etc. etc.
>   TYPE=ERROR, TIMESTAMP=10/03/2015 07:14:59 123 AM, HOST=server1, APPLICATION=app1, FUNCTION=function1, STATUS=null, GUID=null, etc. etc.
>   TYPE=ERROR, TIMESTAMP=10/03/2015 07:14:28 956 AM, HOST=server2, APPLICATION=app1, FUNCTION=function2, STATUS=null, GUID=null, etc. etc.

I need to accomplish the following:

1. What do I need to do to be able to sort results by TIMESTAMP?  It is unsorted right now, because i am enumerating one to many files, and appending results to end of a string.
2. I only want a subset of "columns" returned, such as TYPE, TIMESTAMP, FUNCTION. I thought i could REGEX it in the grep, but maybe arrays would be better?

Results are simply being printed to console/report, as this is only printed for failed tests, and is there for troubleshooting purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this some more, i come to find that one of the key/value pairs allows commas in the values, thus `cut` will not work.  Here is the finished product:

My grep command stays the same, collecting data from all servers:

```
String sh1 = "cat /logs/en/event/event*.log | grep \"" + id + "\" | grep TYPE=ERROR";
Command cmd = s.exec(sh1);
results += IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString();
```

Put the string into an array, so i can process them line by line:

```
String lines[] = results.split("\r?\n");
```

I then used regex to get the data i needed, repeating the below for each line in the array, and for as many columns as needed.  It's a bit of a hack, I probably could have done it better by simply replacing the comma in the offending key/value pair, then using SPLIT() and comma as delimeter, then looping for the fields i want.

```
lines2[i] = "";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("TYPE=(.*?), APPLICATION=.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(lines[i]);

if (m.find()) {
    lines2[i] += ("TYPE=" + m.group(1));
}
```

Finally, this will sort by Timestamp, since it is 2nd column:

```
Arrays.sort(lines2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the list of output that you provided and put it in a file, named test.txt, making sure that each "TYPE=ERROR etc. etc" was in a new line (I guess it's the same in your output, but it isn't clear).

Then I used `cat test.txt | cut -d',' -f1,2,5 | sort -k2` to do what you want.

- `cut -d',' -f1,2,5` basically splits by comma and only reports tokens number 1,2,5 (TYPE,TIMESTAMP,FUNCTION). If you want more, you can add more numbers depending on what token you want
- `sort -k2` sorts according to the 2nd column (TIMESTAMP)

The output I get is:

TYPE=ERROR, TIMESTAMP=10/03/2015 07:14:28 956 AM, FUNCTION=function2

TYPE=ERROR, TIMESTAMP=10/03/2015 07:14:31 253 AM, FUNCTION=function1

TYPE=ERROR, TIMESTAMP=10/03/2015 07:14:59 123 AM, FUNCTION=function1

So what you should try and do, is to further pipe your command with  `|cut -d',' -f1,2,5 | sort -k2`

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, i think the cut solution would work, thus addresses #2.  Do I need to put the data into a different object to be able to sort?  What you see above is the result of after reading all the files.  The sort you have is done at each file, thus end result is still unsorted.

Comment: if the files are not too big, you could cat them together first (combine them), then apply this solution.

Comment: Alternatively, after you filter out the columns you don't like, like shown above, you could store each row into a data structure that you define, add them all into an ArrayList and use Collections.sort(yourList,new Comparator<YourDataStructure>()), where in Comparator you need to define a comparison operator for the time stamp. It's messier but it will work.

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks!  I am running into issues where some of the key pair values contain a column, messing with the cut, but this should be good enough for now.

Comment: i can't cat the files together, since the files are on different servers.  i will explore the data structure.